# How to change components states from another component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an ApplicationHeader component in my applicationn that is called in App.js

**ApplicationHeader.js**

```js
export default class ApplicationHeader extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        loggedUser: null,
      }
  }
  render() {
    return(
        <View style={AppStyle.header}>
          <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <Image source={require('../assets/images/logo.png')} style = { AppStyle.headerLogo}/>
          </View>
          <View style={{flex:0.1}}>
            <Image source={require('../assets/images/bag-topbar.png')} style = { AppStyle.headerBag}/>
          </View>
          <View style={{flex:0.15}}>
            <Image source={this.state.loggedUser !== null ? imgWishListLogged : imgWishList} style = { AppStyle.headerWishlist}/>
          </View>
        </View>
     );
   }
}
```

My **App.js** renders **ApplicationHeader**

```
  render() {

     return (
       <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ bottom: 'never'}} style={styles.container}>
         {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
         <ApplicationHeader />
         <AppNavigator />
       </SafeAreaView>
     );

  }
```

Now, In my **Homepage.js** I would like to send userLogged state or prop to ApplicationHeader to change the icon when user is logged.

```
class Homepage extends Component {
  render() {.....
```

Comment: Why keep it in `ApplicationHeader` state then? Send it as a property. Or use a context, or use a state management system.

Comment: @DaveNewton how could I pass the property through these classes in the scenario above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some attempts, the best way I found was to implement Redux.

Then, with Redux I just used isLoggedUser prop like follow:

```
{!isLogged && ( <Image source={imgWishList} style = { AppStyle.headerWishlist}/>)}
{isLogged && ( <Image source={imgWishListLogged} style = { AppStyle.headerWishlist}/>)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change state to props (or pass the props to the state in your constructor)

```
<Image source={this.props.loggedUser !== null ? imgWishListLogged : imgWishList} style = { AppStyle.headerWishlist}/>
```

and then pass the variable in the props of the `ApplicationHeader`

```
<ApplicationHeader loggedUser={myVar} />
```

---

More info on props [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props)

Comment: Can this prop be changed when user log in application or I can set only once?

Comment: When a prop is changed the component is rerendered

Comment: But how could I pass the instance of ApplicationHeader trough AppNavigator (StackNavigator) and to HomePage? Only App.js knows ApplicationHeader ->
App.js -> ApplicationHeader and AppNavigator
App Navigator-> Homepage...

Answer (score 1):

generally the answer is that you "pass the data higher up" so you don't think about it as "sending from one component to another," you let one component work up the state tree to pass the authentication status higher up in the component tree.

in your example you would not store the state in the lower-level objects, just pass them from the higher components as props.